# dirname equivalent in Go

Tags: file, go, directory, equivalent, dirname

I'm studying Go, I don't know if I missed something, but after searching, I wonder: Does dirname in NodeJS have an equivalent in Go? How to get current directory in Go code, or I have to implement one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Go you can use [`os.Getwd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd) which returns a rooted path name corresponding to the current directory.

```
dir, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Errorf("Dir %v does not exists", err)
}
```

Comment: Isn't that more `process.cwd()` rather than `__dirname`. `__dirname` is the directory of the source file, whereas a working directory as the docs indicate for `os.Getwd` is the user's current working directory (what is executing the program)

Comment: I agree, in practice `.Getwd` and `__dirname__` are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm studying V and Golang at the same time, and apparently, there's a function called `os.Executable()` to have the closest `__dirname` equivalent. According to [this source](https://www.includehelp.com/golang/how-to-get-the-directory-of-the-currently-running-file-in-golang.aspx), you run the `os.Executable()` function to get the directory of where the code is running from, and then do `filepath.Dir()` to get only the absolute path without the executable's name.

I just copy-pasted this snippet from the reference, but this is how you get the `__dirname` in Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    // Getting the path name for the executable
    // that started the current process.
    pathExecutable, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Getting the directory path/name
    dirPathExecutable := filepath.Dir(pathExecutable)

    fmt.Println("Directory of the currently running file...")
    fmt.Println(dirPathExecutable)
}
```

And I agree, there's a difference between what the previous answer did. It also works similarly in V, where it would always get the current working directory from where you ran the code. So if you are in your home directory, when running `os.Getwd()`, it will print out the home directory rather than where you executed the code.